# How to pass the workspace path to a bazel rule

Tags: bazel

seems there is a make env variable `workspace` that [keeps the path value of the original bazel workspace](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/make-variables.html).

But I am not sure how to pass this variable to the bazel rule.

```
exports_files([
  "configure.py", 
])

py_binary(
    name = "configure",
    srcs = [
        "configure.py",
    ],
    data = [
        "//tensorflow/tools/git:gen_git_source.py",
        "//tools",
    ],
    args = [
#        "--workspace=" + $(location workspace), # the path to the repository
        "--tf_workspace=$(location workspace)" , # the path to the 
    ]
)
```

Comment: What are you trying to solve by passing the workspace name to the binary?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Bazel supports neither `$(location workspace)` nor `$(workspace)`.

What makes you think it does?